# User redirected to custom link after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, forms, redirect

I'm trying to code a form which redirects the user depending on what he writes in the form.

If the user writes the word `house` and submits the form, he is redirected to `www.site.com/house`

How to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to redirect user(s) using `PHP`

then

```
if(house_found){
    header('Location: http:www.website.com/house');
}
```

and so on..

Comment: what if i don't have a word list but want to generate the link each time depending on the input?

Comment: can you give me an example of input?

Comment: any words could be an input, the thing i want to do is to have something like a link generation for a search engine, which will create a link with the input inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php if (retrievevalue == "house") {
$link = "www.site.com/house"
header ("Location: " . $link);
}
?>
```

or

```
   <FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="GET" ACTION = "<?php $link ?>">


    <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Login">

    </FORM>
```